# Browsersync crashes Chrome

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, browser-sync, mamp-pro

I have MAMP PRO 5.7 running on a MacBook Pro (8GB RAM). Websites load at `sitename.local.companyname.as` on port 80 with WordPress, nginx, and MySQL. I also use VSCode with composer, Gulp, and browsersync running to do development. Browsersync is set to point to a proxy of port 8181. We're developing WordPress sites using [WP Rig](https://wprig.io/). We are only using `http://` locally, not `https://` (for now).

For a while, browsersync and all browsers were working together just fine. Going to the sites on default port 80 continues to work fine, but at some point the port 8181 access (`http://sitename.local.companyname.as:8181`) just stopped working. Not only that, but it began crashing Chrome and Firefox as well as other apps (like project management software "Hive") that use http connections to send and receive data. Sometimes a few individual tabs will crash (mostly Gmail and Google Calendar tabs). And sometimes the entire browser will shut down.

I've reinstalled MAMP PRO 5.7 but the problem persists. I've looked through all the browsersync and npm stuff I can think of and nothing has been changed from when it was working to when it was not. Short of reimaging my machine and starting over from scratch, I don't know what to do. Below is the output of a typical `npm run dev` command.

```
username@machinename devfilesroot % npm run dev

> wprig@2.0.1 dev
> gulp

[09:02:46] Requiring external module @babel/register
[09:02:47] Using gulpfile ~/local/docroot/wp-content/themes/devfilesroot/gulpfile.babel.js
[09:02:47] Starting 'default'...
[09:02:47] Starting 'cleanCSS'...
[09:02:47] Finished 'cleanCSS' after 14 ms
[09:02:47] Starting 'cleanJS'...
[09:02:47] Finished 'cleanJS' after 1.94 ms
[09:02:47] Starting 'php'...
[09:02:47] Starting 'images'...
[09:02:47] Starting 'scripts'...
[09:02:47] Starting 'scripts'...
[09:02:47] Starting 'scripts'...
[09:02:47] Starting 'scripts'...
[09:02:47] Starting 'styles'...
[09:02:47] Finished 'scripts' after 324 ms
[09:02:49] Finished 'scripts' after 2.18 s
[09:02:49] Finished 'scripts' after 2.19 s
[09:02:49] gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images
[09:02:49] Finished 'images' after 2.37 s
[09:02:50] Finished 'scripts' after 2.85 s
[09:02:51] Finished 'styles' after 4.26 s
[09:02:51] Starting 'editorStyles'...
[09:02:52] Finished 'editorStyles' after 270 ms
[09:02:52] Starting 'libStyles'...
[09:02:52] Finished 'libStyles' after 4.1 ms
[09:03:02] Finished 'php' after 15 s
[09:03:02] Starting 'serve'...
[09:03:02] Finished 'serve' after 6.5 ms
[09:03:02] Starting 'watch'...
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://sitename.local.companyname.as:8181
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
      Local: http://localhost:8181
      External: http://192.168.1.120:8181
 --------------------------------------
      UI: http://localhost:3001
      UI External: http://localhost:3001
 --------------------------------------
```

As you can see, the `Local` URL it outputs is not the same as my `sitename.local.companyname.as` domain scheme. When it was working, I would just put `sitename.local.companyname.as:8181` into the URL bar and it would work the same as `localhost:8181'. But even that doesn't work now.

Here's my `dev.browsersync.bypassPort` setup in my `~/local/docroot/wp-content/themes/devfilesroot/config/config.local.json`.

```
{
  "dev": {
    "browserSync": {
      "https": false,
      "proxyURL": "http://sitename.local.companyname.as:8181",
      "keyPath": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/local.companyname.as/privkey.pem",
      "certPath": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/local.companyname.as/cert.pem",
      "open": false
    }
  }
}
```

Memory:

Baseline is

```
Physical Memory: 8.00 GB
Memory Used: 6.26 GB
  App Memory: 2.08 GB
  Wired Memory: 1.03 GB
  Compressed: 2.51 GB 
Cached Files: 1.29 GB
Swap Used: 0 bytes
```

When I run `npm run dev`:

```
Physical Memory: 8.00 GB
Memory Used: 6.60 GB
  App Memory: 2.99 GB
  Wired Memory: 1.07 GB
  Compressed: 1.89 GB 
Cached Files: 1.34 GB
Swap Used: 0 bytes
```

npm run dev uses 23 MB

Gulp uses 252 MB

MAMP Pro uses 261 MB

Any idea what else I could look into?

Comment: What's your RAM load?

Comment: I've put memory info into the original post for better formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with this line in my config.local.json:

`"proxyURL": "http://sitename.local.companyname.as:8181",`

Which needed to just be

`"proxyURL": "sitename.local.companyname.as",`

The `8181` part is picked up from a config.default.json file as `"bypassPort": "8181",`. But to be extra sure, I overrode that by adding it to the config.local.json file.

Comment: Congratulations with find the cause and documenting the solution.  Thanks